# how can fix wrong output form xpath

Tags: python, xpath

can someone help me with an xpath? i don't know why i get the wrong edition.

[image]

I get

```
Titels: 3. April 2020
```

instead of

```
83
```

-

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

r = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bmandxahj7v2wh2vd2ve7uuzqna&hl=de")

dom = etree.HTML(r.content)

titels_text= dom.xpath('//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/c-wiz[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/text()')[0]

print("Titels:", titels_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would probably use a CSS selector.

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
sel = CSSSelector('span.htlgb')
```

**In case you want to understand Xpaths, you could check this documentation that helped me a lot**
https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#2

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

**But if you want to do really good scraping I recommend you to check this frameworks**
https://scrapy.org/ (This is the most advanced)

https://www.selenium.dev/

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Span with attribute "htlgb" and value of 87 (you've written 83) doesn't exist. Tested with FF,Chrome,Edge. If you want to get the total number of titles, then use this XPath :

```
//tr[@class][last()]//div/text()
```

Output : 87

Comment: can you tell me how you got this now I don't find //tr[@class][last()]//div/text() that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't find..." ? It doesn't work ? I tested it and the XPath expression outputs the desired result (87). Do you want explanations about how I've written the XPath expression (i.e. the meaning of it) ?